# any reason why Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.PageMetaFactory.GetMetaByUrl() is always returning NULL?

Tags: content-delivery, sdl-tridion, sites-9.1, sites-9.5

We recently upgraded Tridion from version Web 9.1 to Web 9.5. On the content delivery side, `Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.PageMetaFactory.GetMetaByUrl()` always return `NULL` on 9.5.

```
var factory = new Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.PageMetaFactory(publicationId);
var meta = factory.GetMetaByUrl(publicationId, uri);
```

Any idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Have you tried one of the overloads that takes a publication, e.g. .GetMetaByUrl(publicationId, url)?

Answer (score 2):

I would raise this with Support.

For the same page in a Tridion Sites 9.1 implementation, I tried using the GetMeta(int pageId) and found it returned null, but GetMeta(string pageUri) does not.

**UPDATE**

Be careful with the parameters your using here, when initialising and calling the method.

The `PageMetaFactory` constructor expects a string or an int. If you pass a string it must be a TCM URI, so not, as in my case(!), a integer as a string, e.g. "19". This is easy to do if your just passing `WebRequestContext.Localization.Id` in DXA.

The same applies, in my case, to the `GetMeta` method, if you pass a string, it must be a TCM URI, not, as in my case(!), an integer as a string e.g. "161091". Again, easy to miss if you just pass `PageModel.Id` in DXA!

Turned out it worked perfectly ... when given the right params!

Answer (score 0):

For this to work I think you need to add the page url including file extension, e.g.: ".html"

Just in case you missed that.

Comment: `uri` param has '/index.html'